# finding text value after a certain div using jQuery

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-selectors, django-forms

To save me a lot of work I'd really like to get the value that is next to a div in my form ( which has been automatically generated by Django formsets )

an example of the output looks as follows:

```
<div class="grid_43 suffix_2">
    <input type="text" name="reward_set-0-for_every" id="id_reward_set-0-for_every">
</div>
<br />
Help text for this particular field
```

How can I get this value that is after the `<br />`

I've tried using a few methods such as `.prev() .next()` different selectors, and now I am all out of ideas.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to target the specific text node, try the following

```
var text_contents = $('.grid_43').parent()
             .contents()
               .filter(function (i, node) {
                  return node.nodeType === 3 && node.nodeValue.replace(/\s|\r/g,'') !== '';
               });
```

this will return an array of non-empty text nodes, from which you can select the required text you want.

In your case use `text_contents[0].nodeValue` to get the required text.

This method will be helpful if you've other textual content inside or outside the `div`.

http://jsfiddle.net/m7CkB/1/

Comment: @Samuel - thanks for replying. based on the variable that you create. Can you perform any other functions with, such as wrap in a div or paragraph?

Comment: @ApPeL of course you can. `text_contents` is an array of text nodes, you can iterate over that and perform any tasks you want.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/r2SnQ/

```
$('.grid_43').parent().text();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#id_reward_set-0-for_every').parent().next().text()
```